# export google cloud auotml model

Tags: text-classification, automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

I have trained, deployed and evaluated a model successfully on google cloud platform's natural language product `AutoML Text & Document Classification`. When i see all deployed models, there is no option to export the model, only delete option is available. Along with exporting data, is there a way to export the automl model as well, so that I can run the model on my local or any other machine?

There are videos explaining to export model in auto ml vision product, but I couldnt draw much similarities with natural language model. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This feature doesn't exist yet for Natural Language product but there is a request for it here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168860629